# Noob trying to make another PSU to Bench power supply

Tags: power-supply

[image: high level view of what I want to do]

Hi, my intention is to make a bench power supply from a PSU. One of the supplied voltages will be variable (0v~30v / 0A~5A).

Well, one of the problems I see is that the display I will use (the one that most use for this project, here: https://www.walmart.com/ip/DC-100V-10A-50A-100A-Voltmeter-Ammeter-LED-Amp-Dual-Digital-Volt-Meter-Gauge/331845591 ) needs to either use the supplied power to power itself too, or an external source.

IF I use the mode that uses the supplied voltage, I will have problems if I vary the voltage below 4v (so, also problems with the 3.3v rail ) as it needs at least 3.6v to work.

So, I have an idea of using the psu's own 5vsb as an "external" source, as it "seems" like the 5vsb comes from a separate rail, from a different transformer (I see it in my psu) and etc, that can supply 5v an up to 2A (all grounds are the same).

My question is, for anyone more knowlegeable than me in computer PSUs and probably the display in question, if I power the display with the 5vsb, if it will work, or if it will short itself somewhere I'm not aware of.

Thanks.

Comment: That diagram is very difficult to read with how you used some kind of outline pen.

Comment: It should work as you want if all the grounds are the same. But that diagram is horrendous.

Comment: Making a bench supply from a PC PSU has been done and discussed many times before, go search on Instructables.com for examples. Then **build the same**. PC PSUs can deliver **huge** amounts of currents so if you do the wrong thing, your wire's isolation will **melt**. So do the right thing and rebuild an existing design. There's simply too much wrong with your "design" so don't build that, it will go up in flames.

Comment: https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/066/649/9b4.gif

Answer (score 1):

Your simple idea is missing all the electronic parts needed to regulate and adjust the voltage and current.

1. Your 12VAC from the transformer will produce a rectified and filtered 15VDC to 18VDC.
2. Your 5VAC will produce a rectified and filtered 5VDC to 8VDC.
   The voltage will vary when the current changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a PC PSU something you should know is that they generally expect a minimum load in order to work properly. If you do not have something already connected that is sucking current the voltage could be quite different from what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone comes across this question:

Yes, it works AS LONG AS you put a diode between the +5vsb and the display.